# Distorted image when apply at least on filter GLSurface

Tags: android, editor, photo, photoeditorsdk

I forked this library on github: [PhotoEditor library](https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor) but I have not changed any part related to effect filter.

My Flow is:
Download with glide a bitmap and after i will send to PhotoEditor library. When i select at least one filter (gray,rotate, ecc...) the image is distorted.

I checked size of bitmap and it is ok. I checked size of surfaceView and it changes when applying the first filter

```
@override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
if (mTexRenderer != null) {
Log.e("ONSURFCHANGED",width+"\nHeight:"+height);
mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
}
```

Before applying filter

[image: Before]

and after

[image: After]

this is the set of filter type: [FILTER TYPE](https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor/blob/master/photoeditor/src/main/java/ja/burhanrashid52/photoeditor/PhotoFilter.java) and this: [File where applies filter](https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor/blob/master/photoeditor/src/main/java/ja/burhanrashid52/photoeditor/ImageFilterView.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was another library that cropped image in ratio wrong!
Thanks